# Unique slick carousel settings per carousel on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my slick carousel settings as a variable which is appended to. However, now that I will have multiple carousels on the same page, each one may have slightly different settings needed.

> It appears that this lies within the definition of the `slickSettings` object. Which is only created once and referenced once. If those `slickSettings` should be unique then you’ll need to create new configs for each, and reference the unique config from `$(this).slick(slickSettings`

Loops through each carousel on the page:

```
$( contentBlockClass + '-masonary__carousel').each(function() {
```

This contains either top-position, bottom-position for each carousel, therefore the value is different per carousel: `contentBlockData.data.masonary_carousel_arrow_position`

If not clear, I need to have multiple unique `slickSettings` per carousel on the page.

**Full Code**

```
var slickSettings = {
arrows: true,
dots: false,
infinite: false,
speed: 300,
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
nextArrow: '<a class="c-arrow"><span class="c-arrow__arrow"></span></a>',
prevArrow: '<a class="c-arrow c-arrow--left"><span class="c-arrow__arrow"></span></a>',
responsive: [
  {
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    },
  },
],
}

var contentBlockClass = '.event-grid-image-over-text-carousel';

$( contentBlockClass + '-masonary__carousel').each(function() {

// @link https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick
// Get our unique ID
var uniqueId = $(this).attr('data-slick-count');

if (typeof contentBlockData === 'object') {
  slickSettings.appendArrows = $('#event-grid-image-over-text-carousel-masonary-' + uniqueId + '__' + contentBlockData.data.masonary_carousel_arrow_position);
}

// Initiate Carousels
$(this).slick(slickSettings)

});
```

Comment: Please don't use a loop to initiate multiple widgets. In the end your code will become obfuscated and everything except readable.

Just initiate each slider based on it's own unique ID with the generic settings you supplied.

Comment: I am working on a page-builder type site, so I won't always know the specific ID of each carousel.

Comment: It's very dangerous to initiate widgets based on classes, because classes do not have to be unique. A more prominent solution would be to scan your content before outputting it, and appending javascript where needed. Besides, if you're using a server-language like `PHP`, you `already know` where you need to put carousels and even what content and settings they need to have. Don't let JS decide in that case, but let your server-sided language decide your output.